# Fusing a google bucket on centos 6.7 permission error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, g-suite, gcsfuse

Currently I'am trying to mount a google bucket to a VM running Centos 6.7.

I have generated a .json file from the developer console and uploaded it to the server, I then went and pointed `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the files location. However when I run gcsfuse, the following error message appears:

`mountFromContext: mount: Mount: mount: Starting fusermount: fork/exec /bin/fusermount: permission denied`

Comment: Try to use `$ sudo gcsfuse` command. If not resolved, use `--debug_fuse` option with command and post the debug output.

Comment: Sudo seemed to work, although in the doc it specifically says not to use sudo. I should have done this sooner.

Answer (score 1):

The problem as I can see is that you are trying to mount on the /bin/fusermount and the /bin directory belongs to root, that is why you managed to mount using sudo.

Probably you created the folder using sudo or the root user otherwise you couldn't create the folder.

You need to change the permission of fusermount/ to the user you want to mount using gcsfuse.

Or create the folder in the home directory of the user you want to mount using gcsfuse.